# How to automatically make a program fullscreen when on a second monitor

Tags: window, fullscreen

Is there a way to automatically display any program window in fullscreen mode (resizing it, magnifier) on a second screen, even if it's not possible with the program itself?

Comment: you should definitely specify the OS.

Comment: @Lukas, Welcome to SuperUser. I noticed an edit attempt specifying Windows as your OS(Operating System) but it was made by a different user. If this was you, please edit using your original account. Tags are a good place to specify OS as well!